# Making one string the anagram of other

Tags: string, python-3.x

I have a problem where two strings of same length are given, and I have to tell how many letters I have to change in the first string to make it an anagram of the second.

Here is what I did:

```
        count = 0
        
        Mutable_str = ''.join(sorted("hhpddlnnsjfoyxpci"))
        Ref_str = ''.join(sorted("ioigvjqzfbpllssuj"))
        
        i = 0
        while i < len(Mutable_str):
            if Mutable_str[i] != Ref_str[i]:
                count += 1
            i += 1
        
        print(count)
```

My algorithm in this case returned 16 as result. But the correct answer is 10. Can someone tell me what is wrong in my code?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What have you tried in terms of debugging? Walk us through a bit more of your thought process.

Comment: Your logic is wrong. Take a simple example: how many letters need to change to make `'abc'` an anagram of `'bcd'`? You only need to change one (`'a'` -> `'d'`), but your algorithm would say three. You can't just compare the sorted strings position-wise.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you're right. Now i see that. Thanks for the explanation. I'll try something different :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Your test works in my `function` below **:)**

Answer (score 1):

**You need to use `str.count`**

So you need to add up the differences between the number of occurrences of each `character` in the different `strings`. This can be done with `str.count(c)` where `c` is each distinct `character` in the second `string` (got with `set()`). We then need to use `max()` on the difference with `0` so that if the difference is `negative` this doesn't effect the total `differences`.

So as you can see, it boils down to one neat little `one-liner`:

```
def changes(s1, s2):
    return sum(max(0, s2.count(c) - s1.count(c)) for c in set(s2))
```

and some tests:

```
>>> changes("hhpddlnnsjfoyxpci", "ioigvjqzfbpllssuj")
10
>>> changes("abc", "bcd")
1
>>> changes("jimmy", "bobby")
4
```